# How to use log loss in sklearn grid search

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn

I am trying use grid search with log loss. Following is my code.

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
df.shape # (146614, 395)
# All features are float32
gbm = GradientBoostingClassifier(max_features="log2")
GSCV = GridSearchCV(gbm, param, scoring=log_loss, n_jobs=2, cv =2, verbose=3)
GSCV.fit(df, y)
clf.grid_scores_
```

However, I am not able to run code. It give me error after long time at GSCV.fit line. however, when I drop scoring = log_loss it works fine.

Can anyone give me advice?

Comment: Are you passing `'log_loss'` as a string or as a function handle (like `metrics.log_loss`) ? What is the error you get?

Comment: It is running for last two hours, where If i drop scoring , model give me answer in 3 min.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **"log_loss"** as string not as function.

Comment: 'log_loss' has been renamed 'neg_log_loss' since 0.20

Answer (score 18):

Try `scoring='neg_log_loss'` in sklearn > 0.18

Comment: This should be the right answer. From the source code: deprecation_msg = ('Scoring method log_loss was renamed to 'neg_log_loss in version 0.18 and will be removed in 0.20.') https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/metrics/scorer.py